# Can one travel to USA with their H1B visa for vacation or do they need travel visa stamped?

Tags: usa, working-visas

Can a person with an Indian passport, H1B visa stamped, visit the USA for vacation with H1B visa rather for work?

- Or does getting travel visa stamped has implications towards the already stamped H1B visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received information regarding this from immigration services, people with the H1B visa can get tourist visa and travel if visiting for vacation. Tourist visa stamp doesn't affect H1B stamp.